# Creating a button with each input JSON object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I got a situation where I would like to read some data off a JSON format, however I am having some issues understanding how I should construct the button dynamically from JSON object.
My scenario is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
  // listen for mqtt_message events
  // when a new message is received, log and append the data to the page
  socket.on('mqtt_message', function(data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data['payload']);
    var table = $("<table>");
    table.append($("<tr><th>Host</th><th>Name</th><th>ID</th><th>"));
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      var row = $("<tr><td>" + json[i]["name"] +  json[i]["ID"] + "</td></tr>");  
      table.append(row);
    }  
    table.appendTo($("#container"));
  })
});
```

where

```
json = {"host":abc,"name":123,"id":345}
```

I have to make hostname as button and when I click on that button for example here, name "abc", i will get details `name` and `id` in table format. I have created table but it is showing whole table not that scenario which I actually want.

I am new to the JavaScript, facing issues here.

Comment: Is there a specific framework you are working with or are you looking for a vanilla javascript solution?

Comment: I am using flask and html templates

Comment: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates - scroll to the loops sections

Comment: vanilla javascript solution would be fine.

Comment: I have never used flask templates. But seems like you could do something like  `<button onclick="showTable()">{{json.abc}}</button>` then at the end (just make sure it loads before you click the button), you should define your function showTable();  which shows you the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The JSON data doesn't seem to be an array, you can't loop through it.

2) You have to append the header to a `<thead>` element.

3) You have to append the table row to a `<tbody>` element.

**All tables should have a `<thead>` and a `<tbody>` element**, so just add it to your HTML code.

```html
 <div id="container">

   <table style="display:none">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Host</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>ID</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody></tbody>
   </table>

 </div>
```

Then you append your data to these HTML elements, like so. If your data is an object and not an array, just don't loop through it but instead call the properties as is.

```js
  var json = [{
     host: "Some host IP",
     name: "Some name",
     id: 345
   },
   {
     host: "Some other host IP",
     name: "Some other name",
     id: 987
   }
 ];

 var $container = $("#container");
 var $thead = $("#container table thead");
 var $tbody = $("#container table tbody");
 var $row = $("#container table tbody tr");

 // Loop through items in JSON data..
 json.forEach(function(item) {
   var $button = $("<button>" + item.host + "</button>");
   $container.prepend($button);

     // Button click handler..
   $button.on("click", function() {

     // Replace row HTML..
     $row.html('<td>' + item.host + '</td>' + '<td>' + item.name + '</td>' + '<td>' + item.id + '</td>');

     // Show table if it's not already visible..
     $("#container table").show();

   });
 });
```

**Full code here:**
https://jsfiddle.net/amsv/15h74uy6/

**Vanilla JS, ie. without jQuery:**
https://jsfiddle.net/amsv/15h74uy6/72/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am able to do it. Thankyou so much.

Comment: what if there are many rows for each table ,what should i change on button on click function?

Comment: Instead of setting `$row` html, you'd set the `$tbody` html. Example: 

https://jsfiddle.net/amsv/15h74uy6/54/

Answer (score 0):

```
let json = [
    {"host":abc,"name":123,"id":345},
    {"host":def,"name":456,"id":345}
]
```

In your html write

```
<button *ngFor = 'let item of json' (click)='buttonOnClick($event)'>
    {{item.host}}
</button>
```

Above code will render two buttons for each element in the array

In your ts write

```
buttonOnClick(event) {
    console.log(event) // you will get the corresponding object from the array
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is giving item is not defined error. @Tridibesh Nag

Comment: Tridibesh Nag ,can you help me ,where your script can be put here to get desired result

Comment: OP is looking for javascript not angular.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sampleData = [{ "host": "abc", "name": 123, "id": 345 }, { "host": "xyz", "name": 456, "id": 678 }]
```

When data is received you should create button which shows table and set data attribute of button with received data.

```
for (var i = 0; i < sampleData.length; i++) {
            var item = sampleData[i];
            var button = $('<button />');
            button.text(item.host);
            button.data('data', JSON.stringify(item))
            button.on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                showTable(e);
            });
            $('#buttons').append(button);
        }
```

showTable is like as below

```
    function showTable(e) {
        var json = JSON.parse($(e.target).data('data'));
        var table = $("<table>");
        table.append($("<tr><th>Host</th><th>Name</th><th>ID</th><th>"));
        var row = $("<tr><td>" + json["host"] + "</td><td>" + json["name"] + "</td><td>" + json["id"] + "</td></tr>");
        table.append(row);
        $("#table").html(table);
    }
```

Html is below:

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="buttons">
        </div>
        <div id="table">
        </div>
    </div>
```